# NLTK - Convert a chunked tree into a list (IOB tagging)

Tags: nltk, nltk-trainer

I need to perform Named Entity Recognition / Classification, and generate output in IOB tagged format.

I'm using a NLTK chunker, as delivered by [NLTK-train library](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train_chunker.html), but that produces a Tree, not a list of IOB tags.

```
def chunk_iob(list_of_words):
    nltk_tagger = nltk.data.load("taggers/conll2002_aubt.pickle")
    nltk_chunker = nltk.data.load("chunkers/conll2002_NaiveBayes.pickle")

    t = nltk_tagger.tag(list_of_words)
    print(t)
    c = nltk_chunker.parse(t)
    print(c)
```

and we get c as a Tree, like:

```
(S
  (LOC Barcelona/NC)
  (PER Juan/NC :/Fd)
```

...

But I am looking for something like:

```
Barcelona - LOC
Juan - PER
...
```

which is the IOB tagged list of the list_of_words parameter, in the same order as list_of_words.

How can I get that tagged list from the tree?

Comment: do they have equivalent pickles for 2.7? I am getting an error running your script

Comment: Note that `NLTK-trainer` is not `NLTK` ;P

Comment: @bogs It seems you have clarity what is IOB , i am afraid i am not get clarity on IOB ,Can you please explain in simple layman term what does it mean inside or outside chunk beginning of chunk with simple example...i believe i understand Chinking and Chunking.. Many thanks Cheers raky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598940/in-natural-language-processing-what-is-the-purpose-of-chunking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is `tree2conlltags` and its reverse `conlltags2tree`. Here's how it works:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk import conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags


tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize("New York is my favorite city")))
print tree
# (S (GPE New/NNP York/NNP) is/VBZ my/PRP$ favorite/JJ city/NN)

iob_tags = tree2conlltags(tree)
print iob_tags
# [('New', 'NNP', u'B-GPE'), ('York', 'NNP', u'I-GPE'), ('is', 'VBZ', u'O'), ('my', 'PRP$', u'O'), ('favorite', 'JJ', u'O'), ('city', 'NN', u'O')]

tree = conlltags2tree(iob_tags)
print tree
# (S (GPE New/NNP York/NNP) is/VBZ my/PRP$ favorite/JJ city/NN)
```

Note that the IOB tags are in this format **B-{tag}** for beginning, **I-{tag}** for inside and **O** for outside.

Comment: Where can one find a list of the meanings of these tags? Also, can someone explain the significance of "beginning" and "inside". Or perhaps point to an existing resource?

Comment: when we chunk sentences, we need to add some annotations, mentioned below are the descriptions of the IOB

B-{CHUNK_TYPE} – for the word in the Beginning chunk
I-{CHUNK_TYPE} – for words Inside the chunk
O – Outside any chunk

They are used to group similar types of entities in a chunk. ex to identify a persons first name, last name

Answer (score 0):

Yes @bogs rightly mentioned it.

**NLTK doesn’t process the data in form of tuples.** So, these tuples are to be converted to trees using the method conlltags2tree() and tress can be converted back to tuples using tree2conlltags()